# Files.move REPLACE_EXISTING cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, file, replace, move

The documentation of `Files.move(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options)` says:

> Alternatively, suppose we want to move a file to new directory,
>   keeping the same file name, and replacing any existing file of that
>   name in the directory:
>
> ```
>  Path source = ...
>  Path newdir = ...
>  Files.move(source, newdir.resolve(source.getFileName()), REPLACE_EXISTING);
> ```

Why do I get an error in the following code then?

```
 Files.move(Paths.get("outputFilePath"), Paths.get("inputFilePath"), REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

> REPLACE_EXISTING cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Did you read the `REPLACE_EXISTING` documentation?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to either write:

```
StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING
```

or:

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING;
```

Note that you may also try and `StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE` if you can

Answer (score 2):

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING;
.......
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says its an argument of interface type `java.nio.file.CopyOption`, which has this implementation (an enum) that you're probably looking for: `java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption` which has a definition for `StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING`